# Dynamic javascript variable name from array

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

I have a variable from php called $blade, for each blade I create a div and graph:

```
<div id="$blade" style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>

g$blade = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("$blade"),"./Data/$node/$blade.txt",{ legend: 'always', title: '$node-$blade', valueRange: [0, 120],visibility: [true, true]});
```

I saved the php blade variable name in a javascript variable:

```
var blades=[];

    foreach ($mabez_blades as &$blade) {
echo <<<AAA

        <script type="text/javascript">
           blades.push("g$blade");
           //console.log(blades);
        </script>
AAA;

}

console.log(blades) -> ["gSC_2_1", "gSC_2_2", "gPL_2_3", "gPL_2_4", "gPL_2_5", "gPL_2_6", "gPL_2_7", "gPL_2_8", "gPL_2_9", "gPL_2_10"]
```

I needed to make a button to transform all this graphs into pics and download them, the problem is I can access one graph with it's name directly,  I can't iterate over the graph names dynamically.

```
    <img id="img" style="display:none"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300" style="display:none" >canvas</canvas>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img = document.getElementById("img"); 
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.style.display="none";
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function saveImage() {
    blades.forEach(function(entry) {
            var filename = entry+".png";
            //Dygraph.Export.asPNG(gSC_2_1, img); //this works for a single graph download
            //Dygraph.Export.asPNG(entry, img); //this doesn't work
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = filename;
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
            link.click();
            });
};
    </script>
```

It produce the following error:

```
Uncaught Type Error: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting of the question?

Comment: Have you firstly Initialized a canvas something like:

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

Comment: inside the function saveImage you do ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0) where img is defined?

Comment: Yes, I do, I didn't want to put in the question s o it wouldn't be too long, I have added it now.

Comment: You should definitely pay attention to variable scope.

Comment: Blades is a global variable so I should be able to access it everywhere. The problem is I can do the graph export if I put the graph name directly, but when I get it as a variable from blades array, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the question, since I was using the $blade as div id, it was considered as div element not just a string. so I put the graph elements in an object with key as $ blade and value as the graph object also changed the div id from $ blade to div$blade.
If someone has better suggestions , I would be thankful to him/her.

```
<div id="div$blade" style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var graphs={};
graphs.$blade = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div$blade"),"./Data/$node/$blade.txt",{ legend: 'always', title: '$node-$blade', valueRange: [0, 120],visibility: [true, true]});

function saveImage() {
            for (var key in graphs){
                    var filename = key+".png";
                    Dygraph.Export.asPNG(graphs[key], img);
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = filename;
                    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                    link.click();
                    }}
```